# Loading XML data into table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a XML like below

```
<MYLIST>
        <Frame Id="89900981" Name="Gxown" Qty="0.0">
          <Frame Id="354653-01" Name="Frametop" Qty="1.0" />
          <Frame Id="656997-23" Name="FrameNM" Qty="1.0" />
          <Frame Id="776879921" Name="PINOBK" Qty="2.0" />
        </Frame>
</MYLIST>
```

Now I want to load the data into table like below

```
+----------+-----------+----------+-----+
| HEAD     | SUBS      | NAME     | QTY |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----+
| 89900981 | 354653-01 | Frametop | 1.0 |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----+
| 89900981 | 656997-23 | FrameNM  | 1.0 |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----+
| 89900981 | 776879921 | PINOBK   | 2.0 |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----+
```

Basically under the `MYLIST` node, the first node `Frame` is the Head of all. So I want to put that as in `HEAD` column (same for all rows under it) and other in `SUBS` column. Is this possible? I have tried using the output `MYLIST_Frame_Frame`. With this i'm able to load the `SUBS`,`NAME` and `QTY` column but the HEAD is available in `MYLIST_Frame`. I'm not sure how to combine this. I have tried using `MERGE` but that is inserting HEAD as a separate row.

Answer (score 1):

> you can use this code in your package:
> The core part of the answer is about using openxml function.
> It has three parameter in which the second one is in xpath format.

```
declare @Xml nvarchar(4000) = '
<MYLIST>
    <Frame Id="89900981" Name="Gxown" Qty="0.0">
      <Frame Id="354653-01" Name="Frametop" Qty="1.0" />
      <Frame Id="656997-23" Name="FrameNM" Qty="1.0" />
      <Frame Id="776879921" Name="PINOBK" Qty="2.0" />
    </Frame>
```

'

```
declare @idoc INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @Xml;
select
    (select
        Id as Head
     from openxml(@idoc, '/MYLIST/Frame', 1) 
     with (Id nvarchar(32))) as Head,
    Id as SUBS,
    [Name],
    Qty
from openxml(@idoc, '/MYLIST/Frame/Frame[position()<=3]', 1)
with 
    (Id nvarchar(32),
     [Name] nvarchar(32),
     [Qty] decimal(2,1))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for SSIS solution not a SQL code.